# Error Calling Python Code from VBA in Outlook

Tags: python, vba, email, outlook, rules

I am trying to run a python script that is triggered by a rule in outlook.  My current process is to write a VBA script that is triggered by the rule - the script simply just calls the shell method as so:

```
Shell (".../Anaconda3/python.exe" & ".../test_email.py")
```

However, when I call the script in VBA I receive the error message "Compile Error: Invalid outside procedure" and the reference to my python exe path is highlighted.  Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?  I've added what I have in the VBA portion with the actual error

---

[image]

---

When I put the code in a sub, I am not able to call the actual code from the rules manager.
[image]

Comment: try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72710085/4539709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a sub which has the following signature:

```
Public Sub Test(mail as MailItem)
   Shell (".../Anaconda3/python.exe" & ".../test_email.py")
End Sub
```

Then Outlook will be able to recognize the method to run for a rule.

See [Outlook's Rules and Alerts: Run a Script](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the code inside a Sub, and then call the sub - not just launch it from the editor.

```
Sub PyExecSub()
    Shell (".../Anaconda3/python.exe" & ".../test_email.py")
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with putting it in a sub then becomes getting the Outlook Rule manager to recognize the script - I can't seem to find a way to call this sub or the script the sub is written in so that the sub can be triggered by the rule. This is a good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

The two answers above are great.  However, I ran into the issue of not being able to track potential errors in my script, so I ultimately ended up creating a .bat file that referenced the python executable and script and created an error logger in the bat.

```
Public Sub PyExecSub(mail As MailItem)
    Shell "...\Desktop\test_email.bat"
End Sub
```